# Examples for increasing homeomorphisms related to $\varphi$-laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\varphi$ be an odd function satisfying $\varphi(s)=\frac{s^3}{1+s^2}$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}_+:=[0,\infty).$ Then $\varphi'(s)=\frac{s^4+3s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}>0$ for $s \neq 0,$ so that  $\varphi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an odd, increasing homeomorphism.

I'd like to find examples of increasing homeomorphisms $\psi_1,\psi_2: \mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$ satisfying
    $$ \varphi(s)\psi_1(t)\le \varphi(st) \le \varphi(s) \psi_2(t)~\hbox{for all }~s,t \in \mathbb{R}_+.\label{f1}\tag{F1}$$

> 1. Are there any examples of $\psi_1,\psi_2$ satisfying \eqref{f1}?
> 2. My question is related to generalized-laplacian problem. Is there any application or physical meaning for $\varphi(s)=\frac{s^3}{1+s^2}$? I would be grateful if you could give any comment related to differential equation.
> 3. Is there any example of $\psi_2$ satisfying \eqref{f1}? Here $\psi_2: \mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$ is a function, not a homeomorphism.

Please let me know if you have any idea or comment for my questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer the mathematical part of your question.

A function $\psi_1$ satisfies F1 for all $s,t\in\Bbb R_+$  iff

$\frac{s^3}{1+s^2}\psi_1(t)\le \frac{s^3t^3}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $s,t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\frac{1}{1+s^2}\psi_1(t)\le \frac{t^3}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $s>0$, $t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\psi_1(t)\le \frac{t^3(1+s^2)}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $s>0$, $t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\psi_1(t)\le\inf_{s\in\Bbb R_+}  t+\frac{t^3-t}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\psi_1(t)\le t^3$  for all $t\in [0,1]$ and $\psi_1(t)\le t$ for all $t\ge 1$. In particular, a homeomorphism $\psi_1$ of $\Bbb R_+$  such that $\psi_1(t)=\min\{t^3,t\}$  for all $t\in \Bbb R_+$ satisfies these conditions.

Similarly, a function $\psi_2$ satisfies F1 for all $s,t\in\Bbb R_+$  iff

$\frac{s^3}{1+s^2}\psi_2(t)\ge \frac{s^3t^3}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $s>0$, $t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\frac{1}{1+s^2}\psi_2(t)\ge \frac{t^3}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $s>0$, $t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\psi_2(t)\ge \frac{t^3(1+s^2)}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $s>0$, $t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\psi_2(t)\ge\sup_{s\in\Bbb R_+}  t+\frac{t^3-t}{1+s^2t^2}$ for all $t\in\Bbb R_+$ iff

$\psi_2(t)\ge t$  for all $t\in [0,1]$ and $\psi_2(t)\ge t^3$ for all $t\ge 1$. In particular, a homeomorphism $\psi_2$ of $\Bbb R_+$  such that $\psi_2(t)=\max\{t^3,t\}$  for all $t\in \Bbb R_+$ satisfies these conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your answer, I don’t understand (4th iff) related to inf. Would you explain it more detail?

Comment: @0706 I made a minor update of the answer.    

Fix any $t\in\Bbb R_+$ and put $f(s)=\frac{t^2(1+s^2)}{1+s^2t^2}$. The inequality $\psi_1(t)\le f(s)$ should hold for each $s>0$. Thus $\psi_1(t)\le\inf_ {s>0} f(s)$. Conversely, if  $\psi_1(t)\le\inf_ {s>0} f(s)$ then $\psi_1(t)\le f(s)$ for each $s>0$.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your answer. $f(s)$ in your comment is not the function in your answer.

Comment: @04170706 Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Now, for $t\ge1,$ $\psi_1(t) \le t^2,$ which does not imply $\psi_1$ is not homeomorphism. Am I wrong?

Comment: @04170706 No, $\psi_1(t)\le 1$ for $t\ge 1$. So $\psi_1(t)\le 1$ for all $t\in\Bbb R_+$ so $\psi_1$ cannot be a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R_+$.

Comment: You are right!  Thanks a lot! There are no homeomorphism satisfying (F1). I should check if there are functions satisfying (F1). Would you have any idea?

Comment: @04170706 Yes. In my answer is shown that a function $\psi_1$ satisfies F1 for all $s,t\in\Bbb R_+$  iff $\psi_1(t)\le t^2$  for all $t\in [0,1]$ and $\psi_1(t)\le 1$ for all $t\ge 1$. In particular, we can put $\psi_1(t)=\min\{t^2,1\}$  for all $t\in \Bbb R_+$. Similarly, a function $\psi_2$ satisfies F1 for all $s,t\in\Bbb R_+$  iff $\psi_2(t)\ge 1$  for all $t\in [0,1]$ and $\psi_2(t)\ge t^2$ for all $t\ge 1$. In particular, we can put $\psi_2(t)=\max\{t^2,1\}$  for all $t\in \Bbb R_+$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that your answer is right. I have something to do right now, so I will check it later.

Comment: Seeing your answer again, we made a mistake, since the numerator of $\varphi$ is $s^3$, not $s^2.$ It may be possible to modify your answer for my question.

Comment: @04170706 Oops, sorry (at my screen this “3” was very similar to “2”). I’ll try to modify my answer.

Comment: @04170706 Done. Now the answer is much more positive. :-)

Comment: Good...Thanks a lot!